# Homeomorphic function spaces arising from homeomorphisms between domains and images?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,X',Y,Y'$ be compact Hausdorff spaces.

Consider the spaces of continuous maps $C(X,Y)$ and $C(X',Y')$ with the topology of uniform convergence.

Is it true that $C(X,Y)$ and $C(X',Y')$ are homeomorphic?

A candidate homeomorphism:

Call the homeomorphisms $h_X : X \to X'$ and $h_Y : Y \to Y'$.
Define $H: C(X,Y) \to C(X',Y')$ by $H(f) = h_Y \circ f \circ h_X^{-1}$.

$H^{-1} : C(X',Y') \to C(X,Y)$ is $H^{-1} (g) = h_Y^{-1} \circ g \circ h_X$.

Note that $H^{-1} \circ H (f) = f$.

We know that a continuous bijection between compact spaces is a homeomorphism.

Thus it remains to show the continuity of $H$, which I fail to do.

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please put the whole question in the body of the question.

Comment: So you ask whether this is true under the condition that $X$ and $X'$ are homeomorphic, and secondly that $Y$ and $Y'$ are homeomorphic? Then the answer is: yes.

Comment: That's a good candidate, but you should also explain your attempts at proving that the candidate is indeed a homeomorphism, and write a focussed question about what troubles you might be having with that proof.

Comment: I’m a real outsider here, but what exactly is uniform convergence in this general context? Wouldn’t your spaces need some kind of uniform structure?